# Is there a way to keep a updated list of AWS Policy services, actions and condition keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I know there are web documentation for such resources (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html)

But Is there a way to retrieve such resources programmatically? Maybe a JSON file that they use to populate such docs? Or somewhere in some SDK? (at least not feasible in aws-go-sdk).

Comment: No. You have to scrape it yourself.

Comment: I think that `boto3` is driven by configuration files. You might be able to peruse the source on GitHub and extract them for other purposes.